# Send broadcast from native service to native module React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to send a broadcast from a background service to a native module and then to react native but I can't get the broadcast receiver in the native module to receive the broadcast. My service is receiving push notifications fine and there's no error when sending the broadcast.

My service looks like this

```
public myService extends CustomService{
    public void sendBroadcastFunction(){
        LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.appName.NOTIFICATION");
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

My native module

```
public class myModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule{
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.d("Houston", "we possibly have a notification");
        if(intent != null){
            Log.d("Houston", "we have a notification");
            Log.d("Houston", "broadcast receiver is working");
            //Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), "Notification received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    };

    public myModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
        super(reactContext);
        reactContext.startService(newIntent(reactContext, myService.class));
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.appName.NOTIFICATION");
        reactContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}
```